# Error when trying to perform CRUD operations to MongoDB from batch file

Tags: mongodb

I am running MongoDB 4.0.13

I want to do some bulk inserts, updates etc from a batch file in windows 10. Here is my simple file:

```
 mongo "my mongo connection string with admin privileges"
 db.logs.insert({'message' : 'inserted from batch'});
 db.logs.insert({'message' : 'inserted from batch #2'});
 exit
```

If I run the command one by one in a command prompt, I get no errors and can do my inserts. The problem happens when i put these lines in a batch file (mongoupdate.bat) I get the following error:

```
 Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("9f44dd9e-b8dd-4c15-a998-ca6c1d1a4de0") }
  MongoDB server version: 4.0.13
 Error while trying to show server startup warnings: user is not allowed to do action [getLog] on 
[admin.]
```

I do not know why I can run the lines of the file one by one in a command prompt, but get this error when running it in a batch file. How do I run MongoDB CRUD operations from a batch file?

Comment: That error implies you're not authenticated to the admin db.  Did you create your users in the admin db or in the target db?  If you created them in admin db, you need to use the authentication database flag on your connection string.  

Have you considered running a javascript file through the Mongo shell instead of running a batch file?

Comment: @VictorWilson - I just created a javascript file and ran it "mongo mongoupdate.js" and it worked. I'll just do this from now on. Thanks

Comment: You can also consider using the [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/index.html).This method allows multiple inserts, updates and deletes on a collection as a batch.